# How can I change the cache path for npm (or completely disable the cache) on Windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed Node.js on my Windows 7 x64 development machine, the manual way:

```
mkdir C:\Devel\nodejs
cd C:\Devel\nodejs
set NODE_PATH=%CD%
setx /M PATH "%PATH%;%NODE_PATH%"
setx /M NODE_PATH "%NODE_PATH%\node_modules"
```

I've placed the main [node x64 binary](http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/x64/) along with [npm package manager](http://nodejs.org/dist/npm/) in `C:\Devel\nodejs`. Works like a charm and I can update the main binary without dealing with the installer.

The only problem I can't solve is moving the cache folder. When I install a local package:

```
npm install express
```

... cache is placed under `%APP_DATA%\npm-cache` folder. I'd like to change it to:

`C:\Devel\nodejs\npm-cache`

How can I change the npm cache folder, or disable it completely?

Comment: Shouldn't the location be: %APPDATA%\npm-cache

Comment: see also [Disable npm cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155072/disable-npm-cache)

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You can change npm cache folder using the `npm` command line. (see https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/config#cache)

So you might want to try this command :

```
> npm config set cache C:\Devel\nodejs\npm-cache --global
```

Then, run `npm --global cache verify` after running this command.

Comment: Also note that if you're going to go down the npmrc route, the global npmrc file isn't located directly at $PREFIX, but rather in $PREFIX\etc

Comment: When doing this on Windows 7 using Cygwin I had to add a forward slash in front of every backslash to avoid the backslashes being removed.

Comment: After executing do a `npm config list` to verify correct setting

Comment: I'm having trouble finding command that you are referring, anywhere in linked document

Comment: Run `npm --global cache verify` after running this command

Comment: I had to use the "environment variable" suggested in another answer because I didn't have `sudo` in the 3rd part image I was building on, and running `npm config set cache` will fail if the root owned files are there.

Answer (score 69):

You can also set an environment variable with `export npm_config_cache=/path/to/cache` (Unix) or `set npm_config_cache=C:\path\to\cache` (Win) as an alternative to `npm config set` (this is true for all config options in npm).

---

For anyone using docker you can add the env var at runtime with:

```
docker run -e npm_config_cache=/path/to/cache mydockerimage:tag
```

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity, why would i change the cache directory using dockers? Which scenario are you aware of that could use benefit of this?

Comment: @fudo it is often useful to use a persistent cache as a volume mount with docker. If I'm running an `npm install` repeatedly in docker, I can mount a cache directory in from my host machine, so I don't lose the cache every time I run.

Comment: This specific approach is also useful if you want to run npm command as a different user. If the user doesn't exist the path to cache directory will be empty. You can verify this by running: `docker run --rm -u 1500:1500 node npm config get cache`. In vanilla node images there is no user with ID 1500.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#environment-variables) is the official documentation of this feature.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do following:

**For having cache path as you wish, for a single package while installing it:**

```
npm install packageName --cache path/to/some/folder
```

**For having cache path as you wish, for all the packages in package.json:**

Just be in the directory where package.json is as usual and do

```
npm install --cache path/to/some/folder
```

You may not find this in npm documentation but i have tried it with npm 6 and it works.
Looks like it works since npm 5 [Refer: [How to specify cache folder in npm5 on install command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310188/how-to-specify-cache-folder-in-npm5-on-install-command])

Answer (score 5):

In Windows you can simply cd to the desired cache folder and do `npm set cache --global`

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Paste the following code into npmrc file.

Location of **npmrc** file: ***C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc***

```
prefix=D:\nodejs\npm
cache=D:\nodejs\npm-cache
```

**Notes:
There is no '.' in front of npmrc**

### Diagrams

#### NPMRC file folder look like this

[image]

#### NPMRC Content look like this

[image]

**Hope it helps. Cheers**

Answer (score -4):

In addition, I found that running an update command works also - for example:

```
npm update npm
```

Lastly, one can check their npm-cache directory to see if is being filled or not.