# Disable npm cache

Tags: node.js, npm

Some time ago I had trouble with the npm cache on our build machines. From time to time we had to do `npm cache clean` by hand, and that solved various issues that we are still not certain about what caused them. So after a time we included `npm cache clean` in all our build scripts, since then we did not have mysterious problems with `npm i`, however now parallel builds obviously affect each other.

For me the best solution seems to be completely turn off the npm caching mechanism, but I couldn't find out how to do that.

Comment: see npm issue [Disabling cache completely](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11338)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could fix the problem with parallel builds by creating a new directory for one series of npm commands and set its `cache` to that empty directory and then remove that directory afterwards. Like:

```
export npm_config_cache=$(mktemp -d) 
npm ...
...
rm -rf $npm_config_cache
```

This would remove the need for `npm cache clean` as it would always start out with an empty cache.

Comment: And why would that series of npm commands use the cache in that new location you just created? What I see here, you create and delete a temp directory, but npm still uses the global cache as usual... What am I missing?

Comment: As on `npm@5` there is no need to export env vars, you can instead run `npm install --cache /path/to/cache` then easily remove it later.

Answer (score 28):

As [npm-config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#force) documented:

> force§
> Default: false
> Type: Boolean
> Makes various commands more forceful.
>
> 1. lifecycle script failure does not block progress.
> 2. publishing clobbers previously published versions.
> 3. **skips cache when requesting from the registry.**
> 4. prevents checks against clobbering non-npm files.

Maybe use `-f` / `--force` is the simplest way to disable npm cache.

```sh
npm install --force
```

Comment: Flag --force does not skip cache in the context you think it would. It still loads the package on the filesystem first

Comment: Does it skip saving the cache? I.e. can I make docker images smaller by `npm install --force`?

Answer (score 20):

In my case, i was facing similar issue **while running multiple instance of 'npm install'** on VM used for build(Windows)

Since it was a VM used only for build there was no other program locking the files. I tried disabling various antivirus settings which didn't worked. "npm cache clear" and "npm cache verify" worked but it was not a right solution for me as i cannot guess when somebody will trigger a build job from Jenkins for different release/environment leading to multiple instance of 'npm install' and hence i cannot add it to the build script nor i can go login to VM and clear/delete the cache folders manually every time.

Finally, after some research, I ended up running "npm install" with separate cache path for each job using following command:

```
npm install --cache path/to/some/folder
```

Since, all the jobs running at the same time now had a separate cache path rather than the common global path (Users/AppData/Roaming/), this issue got fixed as the jobs were no more trying to lock and access the same file, from the common npm cache.

Please note you can install a single package with a cache path as follows:

```
npm install packageName --cache path/to/some/folder
```

I was not able to find this way of giving a cache path in npm documentation but i gave it a try and it worked. **I am using npm6 and looks like it works since npm5 as @ArchNoob mentioned in the comment**