# How to specify cache folder in npm5 on install command?

Tags: javascript, caching, npm, node-modules

In yarn it's possible using `yarn --cache-folder [CACHE_FOLDER]`, what is npm5 alternative?

It's possible to set it with separate command `npm config set cache [CACHE_FOLDER]`, but I'm curious if it's possible to do with just passing some argument to `npm install`

I've checked [v5.0.1 release notes](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v5.0.1) and [`npm install` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) but can't find anything about setting cache folder

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the cache path for npm (or completely disable the cache) on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836053/how-can-i-change-the-cache-path-for-npm-or-completely-disable-the-cache-on-win) (the question refers to Windows, but the answer is applicable to all platforms)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As answered by @maybekatz (npm engineer) [on twitter](https://twitter.com/maybekatz/status/870522066654474240) it's possible using `--cache` argument:

```
npm install --cache [CACHE_FOLDER]
```