# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Sources\**\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'

Tags: npm, package.json

I just updated `npm` to `5.4.0`.
Now, Whenever I want install a npm package I get the following error:

```
D:\Sources\DownloadCms\Md.Download\Web.Angular>npm install mds.angular.datetimepicker@latest --save
npm ERR! path D:\Sources\DownloadCms\Md.Download\Web.Angular\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Sources\DownloadCms\Md.Download\Web.Angular\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Sources\DownloadCms\Md.Download\Web.Angular\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.jso
n'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'D:\\Sources\\DownloadCms\\Md.Download\\Web.Angular\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\ab
brev\\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Sources\\DownloadCms\\Md.Download\\Web.Angular\\node_modules\\fsevents\\node_modules\\abbrev\\package.json' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mohammad\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-09-03T03_25_50_432Z-debug.log
```

I'm dead sure, run `CMD` as administrator.

Also I checked `D:\Sources\DownloadCms\Md.Download\Web.Angular\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev\package.json\`, `package.json` is not exist in path !

**Edit:**
Upgrade to v5.4.1, still get the same error, even cannot work around with --no-optional :-(

Comment: I'm having this issue on npm 8.5.0,  nn-no-optional doesn't work

Comment: All I needed to do, was to stop my dev server and retry the command

Answer (score 103, accepted):

It is an npm 5.4.0 issue https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18287

Workarounds are

- downgrade to 5.3
- try running with --no-optional, i.e. `npm install --no-optional`

Comment: `--no-optional` completely nailed it for me (@5.4.1)!

Comment: if you have opened `VSCode` then close it and try running `npm` command it will be installed definitely, downgrading is not the solution.

Comment: Closing down the VS Code and ran `npm i` from outside worked for me.

Comment: Its fixed in modern versions.

Comment: I have npm version 6.0 and just restarting VScode worked for me.

Answer (score 183):

I was able to fix this by running the command prompt/bash as admin and closing VSCode!
Seems like VSCode was locking some files.
Potentially something else could be locking these files for you.

Comment: In my case, Process Explorer invariably tells me that the culprit locking the files `npm` is trying to delete is… another `node.exe` process spawned by `npm` running `npm`! Oh joy, this tool never ceases to surprise… (this is on Windows 10, Node 12.11.0, npm 6.11.3)

Comment: why the hell `vscode` is failing the installation of angular app?

Comment: +1 For closing any running processes that may be hanging onto the file - I had vue-cli-service serve running.  Closing that solved it for me.

Comment: +1 - note for me I also had to close all the orphaned(?) instances of node.js that seem to build up over time when debugging in vscode on windows

Comment: `VS Code` locked a file in my case, which was fixed after restarting VS Code. The error was : `An unhandled exception occurred: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink fa-regular-400.1495f578452eb676f730.ttf`

Comment: running the cmd as administrator worked for me, thank you! `[+1]`

Comment: I wasn't even running my app from the vscode terminal but for some reason vscode still locked my prisma related file.  Thanks for the fix.

Comment: This was only a temporary solution :(

Answer (score 23):

Please close all IDE like visual studio code. run npm install command through node.js command prompt.
**Enjoy !**

Comment: In some cases need to restart system.

Comment: Also check .NPMRC file

Answer (score 18):

cache clean and `npm` update to latest with force work for me

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest --force
```

Answer (score 17):

If you downgrade to 5.3 and still get the same error in Windows like me.
After hours working with npm versions I found the following solution:
**1.** Download latest recommended version of `nodejs`, these days is `node-v6.11.3-x64`
**2.** Uninstall `nodejs` with it.
**3.** Go to `C:\Users\{YourUsername}\AppData\Roaming` folder and delete `npm` and `npm-cache` folders
**4.** Run installer of `nodejs` again and install it
**5** Update npm to 5.3 with `npm i -g npm@5.3` command line
Now you should use npm without any issues.

Comment: `npm i -g npm@5.3 --no-optional` worked for me

Answer (score 13):

I tried this solution found at a [How to fix Node.js blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/matt-harrington/2012/02/23/how-to-fix-node-js-npm-permission-problems/)

just use

```
npm cache clean
```

in windows if it refuses use

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Windows in CI on VSTS (now Azure DevOps)

Answer (score 11):

I fixed by downgrading npm from 5.4.0 to version 5.3

```
npm i -g npm@5.3
```

I Hope this helps for you

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem on Windows.

The source of the problem is simple, it is access permission on folders and files.

In your project folder, you need

1. After cloning the project, change the properties of the folder and change the permissions of the user (give full access to the current user).
2. Remove the read-only option from the project folder.
   (Steps 1 and 2 take a long time because they are replicated to the entire tree below).
3. Inside the project folder, reinstall the node (npm install reinstall -g)
4. Disable Antivirus. (optional)
5. Disable Firewall. (optional)
6. Restart PC.
7. Clear the npm cache (npm clear)
8. Install the dependencies of your project (npm install)

After that, error "**Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink**" will no longer be displayed.

Remember to reactivate the firewall and antivirus if necessary.

Answer (score 9):

For those who are coming from Windows OS, you just need to stop the development server and then execute your `npm install ...` command.

It is strange how Windows doesn't allow installing dependencies while server is running, but MacOS does allow.
If this doesn't work, then only go for the other options - clean cache, downgrade nodejs etc.

Comment: Been pulling my hair for hours. Turns out i had a GIt Bash running the dev server. Thanks

Comment: What's the development serveR?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and all I needed to do was login to npm

`npm login`

or alternatively

`npm add user` // consult the documentation for the params

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem was that, **I did not install typescript**. Although I did install Node and Angular. 
To check if you have installed typescript or not

```
Run this command: tsc -v
```

If not, then to install typescript

```
Run this command: npm install -g typescript
```

And, finally to install required dependencies

```
Run this command: npm install
```

in the root folder of the project.

---- Hope this helps someone ----

Comment: I faced this issue when I was trying to install yeoman as mentioned here - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension. Installing typescript solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

If all of the above failed to work for you, you might want to

- restart your system
- run command prompt as admin
- run the npm command

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `VsCode` and solved this issue by stopping the application server and them run `npm install`. There are files that were locked by the application server.

No need to close the IDE, just make sure there's no another process locking some files on your projects.

Answer (score 4):

Mine was as a result of opening my project folder a 2 different terminals. I **solved** it by **closing all running terminal** (vs code was excluded) and executing the installation command again.

I hope this helps someone.

**NB:** deleting node_modules didn't solve it.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this by removing the dist folder

--- Remove dist or public folder

Answer (score 4):

just close the working operations inside the project

Answer (score 3):

I had this logs in Windows.
I did the following

- Close Visual Studio Code
- Run Command Line as admin

Answer (score 3):

Deleting package-lock.json fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting my node modules folder and running a normal npm install did it for me

Answer (score 3):

For me it was Docker...

The moment that I closed the app container, I could do an npm install without any proble

P.S My node version is 14.15.5

Answer (score 2):

For me it worked in bash from git package
try:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
```

then:

```
npm install mds.angular.datetimepicker@latest
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be many solutions out there that worked with downgrading npm versions.  For me, the solution was

```
npm install -force
```

I tried the downgrading of npm versions, modifying my npm prefix config to match the npm directory, and clearing cache.  None of these worked, but apparently they worked for others, so it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

For me on Windows the problem was **too long path length**. I moved the project to a smaller length path and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything, including node/npm upgrade, cache cleaning and reverting code, nothing helped besides one simple thing: **Turning OFF Windows 10's Real-time protection** during the dev/build. Looks like latest updates made it super aggressive.

Answer (score 2):

`npm login` is required before `publish`

Answer (score 2):

in my case i try to deploy my serverless app and showing this error,i've tried all the solution above and not works,unexpectedly the solution is as simple as delete the .build folder and try redeploy, **voila everythings good!**. try to delete the node_modules or build folder.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to closing VS CODE I also had to run this command

```
taskkill -F -IM node.exe
```

to stop the node process as my test server was still running which was causing the install error.

Answer (score 1):

the same error comes to me when i update the npm version to the latest 5.4

downgrade to the version 5.3.0 is useful.the error comes from the npm 5.4,you can check it in the [issuses in npm 5.4](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18287)

```
npm install npm@5.3 -g
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in NPM 5.6.0

Upgrade to NPM 5.6.0 solved problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to run npm install from within my external hard drive as this is where i saved my code workspace. Windows 10 OS.

But I was getting the same error as the original post.None of the previous answers worked for me, I tried all of them:

1. uninstalling nodejs then re-installing
2. uninstalling nodejs then downgrading/installing a lower version of nodejs.
3. npm install -force
4. deleting the folders from C:\Users{YourUsername}\AppData\Roaming ... npm and npm-cache then re-installing.
5. npm cache clean --force
6. npm cache clean
7. npm install --g or npm install --global

What worked for me was this:

1. copy the folder from C:\Program Files\nodejs to D:\Program Files\nodejs
2. Then go to Control Panel\System and Security\System
3. Advanced System Settings
4. Environment Variables
5. System Variables
6. Double click Path
7. Add a new path
8. D:\Program Files\nodejs
9. Click ok
10. restart PC.
11. try npm install from within D: Drive

Answer (score 1):

`npm cache verify` solved my issue.
I was doing: `ng new my-app`
and I faced similar error

I have 
node version: 10.16.0 
npm v 6.9.0

Answer (score 1):

I simply completely shutdown , NOT hibernated, my machine and restarted it.
Ran the CMD as admin and used npm install command. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was facing similar issue **while running multiple instance of 'npm install'** on VM used for build(Windows)

Since it was a VM used only for build there was no other program locking the files. I tried disabling various antivirus settings which didn't worked. "npm cache clear" and "npm cache verify" worked but it was not a right solution for me as i cannot guess when somebody will trigger a build job from Jenkins for different release/environment leading to multiple instance of 'npm install' and hence i cannot add it to the build script nor i can go login to VM and clear/delete the cache folders manually every time.

Finally, after some research, I ended up running "npm install" with separate cache path for each job using following command:

```
npm install --cache path/to/some/folder
```

Since, all the jobs running at the same time now had a separate cache path rather than the common global path (Users/AppData/Roaming/), this issue got fixed as the jobs were no more trying to lock and access the same file, from the common npm cache.

Please note you can install a single package with a cache path as follows:

```
npm install packageName --cache path/to/some/folder
```

I was not able to find this way of giving a cache path in npm documentation but i gave it a try and it worked. **I am using npm6 and looks like it works since npm5.**

[Refer: [How to specify cache folder in npm5 on install command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44310188/how-to-specify-cache-folder-in-npm5-on-install-command])

This solution should work for other scenarios as well though may or may not be a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

This was the only thing that worked for me:

```
npm cache clean --force

npm install -g npm@latest --force

rm package-lock.json

npm i -force
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem just doing an npm install.
Run with antivirus disabled (if you use Windows Defender, turn off Real-Time protection and Cloud-based protection). That worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

try running :- 'rm -rf node_modules && npm i' . it worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

Having watched my Windows Defender Virus Scanner start hogging the CPU while running my script, I suspect this is the actual cause, but as I don't have the ability to tweak those settings as I'm in a commercial domain.

As my script fails while doing `npm install`, I simply tried this instead

```
npm install --verbose
```

which allowed it to run perfectly. It probably doesn't fix the underlying issue, but it allowed my install to download and extract all dependencies to my local cache at least once and therefore, everything worked a lot smoother.

I presume this command slows the writes/read to the disk by a fraction of a second, while its writing to the Command prompt and this gives the virus checker, just enough time to finish its work, without creating a deadlock on the files.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, VS code was opened and also the application was running on the metro bundler, so I just close the metro bundler and use the install command again and it got worked.

Answer (score 1):

This did the magic for me:

1. Close all editors/IDEs and other open consoles.
2. Open a new cmd prompt in the project folder.
3. Run the command `npm install node-sass@^4.14.1`
4. Run the command `npm install --no-optional`

P.S.: My node version was above 14.

Answer (score 1):

For me npm cache clean --force

and restart

Worked Fine!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the node process that I was debugging that had a lock on some native compiled node-gyp type modules.

As the .node file is effectively a DLL/shared object, the calling process needs to keep a lock on the file so that it can load pieces of the file on demand. If the file were suddenly removed, it would be a problem for the running process.

Stopping the node process being debugged resolved the issue in my case.

Not seeing an answer here that covers this scenario. If this covers your case then it's a quicker resolution than closing or rebuilding everything.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried ALL the solutions here. Then I've came up with a solution on a [blog](https://www.nigglingaspirations.com/posts/09/29/2020/npm-pack-nowork-gradle-wrapper). If someone using node-gradle plugin and facing this issue, the following solution might help.

for your .gitignore or .npmignore file, add the following :

```
# Gradle
.gradle/
```

It seemed totally irrelevant to me, but after spending 1.5 day on this stupid issue, finally it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when "you re-create directory" but already have a shell at this location, so we could simply run in terminal:

```
cd ~ && cd -
```

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKED FOR ME

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}

then update ,

npm i -g npm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are running 'npm run dev' or 'npm run watch'. If you do, then exit it and re-run 'npm install "package"'.

**I hope it works!!!**

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your nodejs version node >=16
2. Update npm version to latest
3. npm cache clean --force
   Try again it should work

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly because of windows security in your pc.
I have solved issue by running project in cmd terminal (as administrator)

Answer (score 0):

For windows,

1. Download latest recommended version of `nodejs`, these days is `node-v6.11.3-x64`
2. Uninstall nodejs with it.
3. Go to `C:\Users\{YourUsername}\AppData\Roaming` folder and delete `npm` and `npm-cache` folders
4. Run installer of `nodejs` again and install it
5. By default `npm 3.10.10` should be installed along with `node-v6.11.3-x64`.
6. It worked for me with `npm 3.10.10` but did not work with `5.3.X`.
   Also it did not worked with higher versions of node (above
   `node-v6.11.3-x64`)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was executing the command (npm audit fix all). I solved it when closing VSCODE and re-executed the command without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and was not able to solve the problem with any of above mentioned solutions.So I tried moving my project directory to some other location on Desktop.Then it showed, could not do this as it is running, even though I hadn't opened that file in any text editor or so.So what I did was to type resmon.exe in Run commandbox and then clicked the CPU option.Then enlarged the associated handles section and type in the name of my project directory.It showed some processes that were running that directory so I selected them and right clicked them and clicked End Process.
Then i was able to cut paste my project directory to some other location on desktop and then i ran npm install commands and was able to successfully execute the.[check out this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZLur.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: thanks and i will definitely check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just "Restart your system" and try to delete that file again. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRd16.png) [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Yogesh\Desktop\hooks\my-app\node_modules@firebase\analytics-compat\dist\index.cjs.js'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'unlink',

I got a similar error but there was a network issue while installing firebase I recommend seeing an internet connection while installing firebase since small fluctuations may also give the error.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557