# React Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd

I am learning react and trying to create react app from command line in windows 10. But it gives an error in middle of the process. Below is the error log.

My node version is v10.8.0 and npm version is 6.2.0

I am using below command to create the app.

```
D:\react>create-react-app myappreact

Creating a new React app in D:\react\myappreact.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! path D:\react\myappreact\node_modules\.staging\url-parse-6c16a96d\index.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\react\myappreact\node_modules\.staging\url-parse-6c16a96d\index.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\react\myappreact\node_modules\.staging\url-parse-6c16a96d\index.js']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\react\myappreact\node_modules\.staging\url-parse-6c16a96d\index.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'D:\\react\\myappreact\\node_modules\\.staging\\url-parse-6c16a96d\\index.js' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'D:\\react\\myappreact\\node_modules\\.staging\\url-parse-6c16a96d\\index.js\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'D:\\react\\myappreact\\node_modules\\.staging\\url-parse-6c16a96d\\index.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'myappreact' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: Which version of node and npm are you using

Comment: Did you visit this thread https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380. It has solution looks like you need to downgrade your npm to 5.3 if you are using 5.4. Check this thread

Comment: @Think-Twice My node version is v10.8.0 and npm is 6.2.0

Comment: Have you tried solutions given in the github?

Comment: @Think-Twice I am looking into that.

Comment: Check this thread as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020018/error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-d-sources-node-modules-fseven

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Sources\‌\*\*\node\_modules\fsevents\node\_modules\abbrev\package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020018/error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-d-sources-node-modules-fseven)

Comment: @Think-Twice I downgraded node to 8.9.4 and npm to 5.3.0. Now when I run create-react-app command to create a react app I get this error "npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:37601
npm ERR! KUj6OKBcR9fQcl1NvUOTWNaJ6mw==","shasum":"49efeea6e8058d5af860a18a6de8"

Comment: Do npm cache clean --force and delete existing project. create new project with create-react-app projectname

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178793/discussion-between-think-twice-and-amit-rawat).

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I simply turned off my Windows Defender Real-time protection and ran the create-react-app command again, then the problem has been solved.

Comment: So you are saying we will have to remove existing application and recreate it? nice

Comment: The problem was because of create-react-app commad.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all text files on npm-cache logs folder. It worked for me.

C:\Users\***yours***\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs

Answer (score 0):

I was also learning React and the same problem also come so ,I just copy paste the react file in c drive and it runs fine.