# npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: javascript, windows, npm, expo

- OS : Windows 10.
- npm version : 6.9.0
- node version : 12.4.0

I'm working on an expo application.
I would like to install all the packages on my expo application (npm install). But, an error occured :

`17254 error  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ...`
I have seen this error on many subjects, but no one answer to my problem.

I've already tried to :

1. Launch my terminal as an administrator.
2. npm config set safe-perm=true.
3. npm install --no-bin-links
4. npm cache clear --force

An exemple of error message that I have :

````
17254 error   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\someDirectory\someDirectory\someDirectory\someDirectory\node_modules\.staging\react-native-99ed309f\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactFabric-dev.js'] {
17254 error     errno: -4048,
17254 error     code: 'EPERM',
17254 error     syscall: 'unlink',
17254 error     path: 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\node_modules\\.staging\\react-native-99ed309f\\Libraries\\Renderer\\oss\\ReactFabric-dev.js'
17254 error   },
17254 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink ' +
17254 error     "'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\node_modules\\.staging\\react-native-99ed309f\\Libraries\\Renderer\\oss\\ReactFabric-dev.js'",
17254 error   errno: -4048,
17254 error   code: 'EPERM',
17254 error   syscall: 'unlink',
17254 error   path: 'C:\\Users\\Thomas\\Desktop\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\someDirectory\\node_modules\\.staging\\react-native-99ed309f\\Libraries\\Renderer\\oss\\ReactFabric-dev.js'
17254 error }
17255 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
17255 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
17255 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
17255 error
17255 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
17255 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
17255 error the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
17256 verbose exit [ -4048, true ] ```
````

Comment: The 'Libraries' directory doesn't exists, indeed. But this error also happen on directory that exists, like 'RnTester-js-Tester App.ios', but file inside doesn't.

Comment: There's a bunch of solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020018/error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-d-sources-node-modules-fseven) that you could check out.

Comment: cleaning the build folder and rebuilding helped me

Answer (score 8):

Is there a another instance of node running, that is also using ReactFabric-dev.js? If so, terminate and retry. Also try to move your project to a folder "closer" to root. Windows sometimes gets confused with very long paths.

Comment: There isn't another instance of node that is running on my computer. I restarted it, and nothing change...

Answer (score 4):

Solved it by logging into npmjs:
`npm login`

or

uninstall all npm modules and re-install with `npm install --no-bin-links`

or

```
rd /s /q C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
rd /s /q C:\Users\foo\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did is:

1. Deleted node_modules folder;
2. Opened VSCode as administrator;
3. Ran the following commands in terminal:

   `npm cache clean --force`

   `npm install`

Comment: It might be a bit confusing to require the VSCode terminal. As far as I can see, every terminal that is run as an administrator would do fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error message, to solve it you have to:

1) add your project folder in [Windows Defender exclusions list](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security).

2) remove your node_modules folder

3) run:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it globally first, using the command

- npm install -g create-react-app

And then, you can create your app using the command,

- npx create-react-app <Name_of_your_app>