# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted NPM ISSUE

Tags: npm

When I do npm install express I get this error

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj57p.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56700018/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink).

Comment: Have you [tried this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34614939/3758602). Usually it's caused by a change in the npm default directory path, to where you don't have permission to execute that command. Try to cross check the npm config file with `npm config edit` and change the prefix back to the default `Change prefix variable to C:\Users\<YourUserName>\AppData\Roaming\npm`