# Issue In Installing Packages On Windows 10

Tags: npm

I have a angular project on bitbucket which I cloned into my desktop having OS Windows 10. The folder already has `package.json` and `package-lock.json`.

When I hit command `npm install` inside the project, it runs for around 2 minutes and then it gives two errors and stops:
1.) Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 2.) npm err! enoent No such file or directory continuously.

I have tried all possible following things:
1.) Run as administrator.
2.) Reinstalled nodejs and run.
3.) Cleared cache and verified using npm commands.
4.) Deleted npm and npm-cache folders and re run again.
5.) Downgraded npm version and re-run again.
6.) Deleted package-lock.json and re-run again.
7.) Gave folder permission fll control and re-run again.
8.) Stopped antivirus and disabled firewall and re-run again.

All above execution didn't solve the problem.

Can you please help me out?
My nodejs version is :- 10.16.3 and npm version is :- 6.9.0

Comment: Try uninstalling Windows and use Linux, It would solve your problem!

Comment: Yes, that would work, but most of the system I have is of windows, so reinstalling all would be more tedious task, hence any solutions for this would be more suitable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\Sources\‌\*\*\node\_modules\fsevents\node\_modules\abbrev\package.json'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020018/error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink-d-sources-node-modules-fseven)

Comment: Even tried the solutions mentioned in the given link given  by you, but no luck.

Comment: Any update guys ?