# My npm globally installed packages don't work

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, node-modules

I installed a cute-files npm package globally (it doesn't matter it could be anything else), I expect when I run:

```
cute-files
```

I will see result but now I see cute-files isn't a command.

I should tell you I changed my npm directory because  of some permission errors and now my npm directory is:

```
/home/nima/.npm-g/lib/node_modules
```

And one more point when I run this command:

```
echo $NODE_PATH
```

I see no results and when I set node path with this command:

```
NODE_PATH="/home/nima/.npm-g/lib/node_modules"
```

it doesn't fix my problem and after few minutes NODE_PATH again changes to nothing!

I googled very much but I couldn't fix this.

Comment: uninstall npm and nodejs, then set it up correctly

Comment: use npm link package-name in the current working directory. This command will create a symbolic link from globally installed package to node_modules/ of the current folder.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836053/how-can-i-change-the-cache-path-for-npm-or-completely-disable-the-cache-on-win

Comment: @baao  thanks for your comments, I solved it by changing again the npm directory

Comment: @Dileephell thanks for your comments, I solved it by changing again the npm directory

Comment: @davin-tryon thanks for your comments, I solved it by changing again the npm directory