# How do you move the nodejstmpcache folder to its original location?

Tags: node.js, npm, caching, npm-cache

I recently ran some npm cache code on the terminal which started making the **nodejstmpcache** folder on my root project directory whenever I run an npm command. It comes back even if I delete it when I run npm command next time on the console. How do reset this back to its normal location?

I tried the verified Answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836053/how-can-i-change-the-cache-path-for-npm-or-completely-disable-the-cache-on-win) but now the folder name just changed to "USERPCNAME".

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just uninstall and reinstall nodejs that will work.

- Go to the control panel
- click on programs
- find nodejs and uninstall it
- Then you can just install the latest version of nodejs from the internet and It will work as good as new